# Create Relationship from CSV Import Adding a Relationship Property

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have created a set of nodes from a CSV import and labelled them as 'Argument'.

I have another CSV file which contains Connector_ID, Start_Object_ID, End_Object_ID which I want to:

1. Create the relationship (from start object to end object)
2. Add the value of the Connector_ID to the relationship created

At the moment I've only got as far as failing to create the relationships (valid syntax but does nothing) using:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/argument_has_part_argument.txt" AS row
MATCH (argument1:Argument {object_ID: row.Start_Object_ID})
MATCH (argument2:Argument {object_ID: row.End_Object_ID})
MERGE (argument1)-[:has_part]->(argument2);
```

but cannot yet see

1. why it fails to do anything
2. how to get it to create a relationship
3. and  how to add the Connector_ID to the connector so created.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you read this: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_csv_data_quality ? Esp. the cypher statements to check your data quality. Can be typos or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_csv_data_quality

Cypher

What Cypher sees, is what will be imported, so you can use that to your advantage. You can use LOAD CSV without creating graph structure and just output samples, counts or distributions. So it is also possible to detect incorrect header column counts, delimiters, quotes, escapes or spelling of header names.

```
// assert correct line count
LOAD CSV FROM "file-url" AS line
RETURN count(*);

// check first few raw lines
LOAD CSV FROM "file-url" AS line WITH line
RETURN line
LIMIT 5;

// check first 5 line-sample with header-mapping
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file-url" AS line WITH line
RETURN line
LIMIT 5;
```

For your last question:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/argument_has_part_argument.txt" AS row
MATCH (argument1:Argument {object_ID: row.Start_Object_ID})
MATCH (argument2:Argument {object_ID: row.End_Object_ID})
MERGE (argument1)-[r:has_part]->(argument2)
ON CREATE SET r.connector_ID = row.Connector_ID;
```

Comment: The thing preventing relationships being created was that 'Object ID' is defined as an integer and the CSV had an integer as a string. The solution was to use {objectID: toInt(row.Start_Object_ID)}